# Why does my layout ignore Constraint Layout Guideline?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am having a Guideline in a Constraint Layout that I use to anchor a `LinearLayout` to keep to its left as follows:

[image]

So, you can see the `Guideline` a bit right to middle and between `LinearLayout` on the left and the `ImageView` to the right.

Now, when I run the App and set the text of *Skill Set* or *Tutor Types* or *Location* considerably large, it crosses the GuideLine to being behind the `ImageView` as follows:

[image]

*(**Note**: This is NOT a real person's data but mock data)*

If you see the XML, you will find that the `LinearLayout` is indeed meant to be anchored **to_left_of** the `Guideline` but that doesn't happen.

So, what is the problem here? Is there a bug in Constraint Layout or am I missing something?

---

**Layout for reference:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:background="@color/lightGrey"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:elevation="2dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/tutor_name"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tutor_name"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/tutor_skill_set"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:id="@+id/skill_set"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/tutor_types"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:id="@+id/tutor_types" />

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/tutor_location"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp" />

    </LinearLayout>



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:id="@+id/display_pic"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0" />

    <com.iarcuschin.simpleratingbar.SimpleRatingBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tutor_rating"
        android:layout_below="@+id/display_pic"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        app:srb_starSize="13dp"
        app:srb_numberOfStars="5"
        app:srb_borderColor="@color/blue"
        app:srb_fillColor="@color/blue"
        app:srb_starBorderWidth="1"
        app:srb_isIndicator="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/display_pic"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/display_pic"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tutor_requested_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:text="Requested time"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tutor_rating"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.6796875" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: obvious solution is to change `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_width="0dp"` in `LinearLayout`

Comment: @Selvin : Let me try that...

Comment: It will work as `0dp` means something like  "compute based on where view lie" while `wrap_content` means "compute based on children"

Comment: @Selvin : It works! Thanks and I got your reasoning and shall remember that in future. If you like, post this as an answer and I shall accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: @Selvin Added answer based on your comments as a Community post. Will gladly remove the post if you add your own answer

Answer (score 1):

Change the `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` property of the `LinearLayout` to `android:layout_width="0dp"`.

This will work because setting the `layout_width` to `0dp` means that the width for the `LinearLayout` will be computed based on the constraints placed on it. Whereas if the width is set to `wrap_content` the width will be computed based on the size of it's child views.